# Magento Bundled Products from Product ID

Tags: php, magento

I've been struggling for few days now over a particular task in a magento store.

On every product page, i want to get dynamically those bundles which have this product in them.

Can anyone please get me into the right direction or give me some tips?!

THANKS!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far over the last few days? What problems are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add the bundled products in the 'Up Sells' Section of the Product Information.

Comment: aaaa... wise tghought!! Tough my client wants to use the up sells and this request on a separate manner.

I'm accepting this as an answer.. thanks for sharing!